# can't open file using c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I am using linux g++ compiler and also visual studio code to compile and run the code below and each time I run it, it returns with could't open file. i have put the text file in the same folder as the c++ program but still to no avail.
Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 1) {   
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << "filename.txt" << endl; 
    }

    ifstream ifile(argv[1]);

    if (ifile.fail()) {
        cerr << "Could not open file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your text file in the same folder as the compiled executable? What is the current directory when you run the executable?

Comment: yes it is, the current directory after running is the path of the folder that the executable and the textfile are contained in.@heapunderrun

Comment: Have you tried hard coding the file name? Have you tried outputting the value of `argv[1]`? Have you tried a different file? The way you solve this kind of problems is by testing the assumptions you are making, until you find the one that is wrong.

Comment: 80% of the code in your question can be removed and still demonstrate your actual problem.  And doing this will cut down the noise for the rest of us, please see [mre].

Comment: What is the command you are using to run your program?

Comment: I use ./ to run it after being compiled by g++ @Aamir

Comment: Are you providing the file name as first argument to the executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have given the filename to the program as an
   argument.

   After being compiled by g++, you should run the program like this:

   ```
   ./program filename.txt
   ```

   `argv[1]` is the first program argument, in this case
   "filename.txt".
2. Make sure that whatever launches the program is in the same working directory
3. Make sure that the file program has sufficient permissions to read the file. This can be changed with `chmod`.

Comment: your answer was very helpful. wish I can upvote it @Cedric Martens

Comment: @darui you can set it as the accepted answer